# Java, something instead of while(true) loop

Tags: java, loops, callback, while-loop

I have developed virtual keyboard module, it contains 2 classes

1. KBM (the module itself) (on enter press it sets value of String data to the text i typed in KBMListener, and Boolean changed to true in KBMListener)
2. KBMListener
3. MainFrame

What is doing mainFrame:

When I run the program MainFrame loads the GUI and starts "while(true)" loop in "public void run()". This loop look like :

```
while(true){
    if(status_changed){
        jTextArea.setText(getKbml().getData());   
        getKbml.setStatus_changed(false);
    }
    sleep(500);
}
```

The boolean status_changed is changed in a keyboard Listener.

KBM is the virtual keyboard. When the user type text and press enter, it set the String data to text typed and boolean status_changed to true in KBMListener.

KBML just connects the MainFrame with KBM and loads the keyboard from KBM everytime the user clicks into textarea in mainframe.

What I want is every 0.5 sec or instantly get value to mainframe when enter is pressed.

While loop is working good, but cpu usage is around 12% on 1.6GHz dualcore processor.
I heard about callback but I can not understand how it works. I hope somebody can help me... Try to avoid document listener please.

Comment: Why did you post invalid pseudo-code within a paragraph, instead of posting *actual* code - even if it's simplified - as code? Your question is much harder to understand at the moment.

Comment: Show whatever you have tried in code..That would be much understandable than this big description of code..

Comment: Why do you not want to use a DocumentListener - that would seem to me to be precisely what you need to implement this efficiently...

Comment: its stand alone module, i want to use it in other apps with import without modification of code in module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to look into is the Observer design pattern. It uses an interface to notify 'listeners' of changes, and is often the answer to infinite loops. You can find a simple implementation example + more information here : http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered

Or simply search the web for "observer pattern java".

Comment: public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable, how i can extend with obser. if it extends with JFrame?

Comment: @user1934053 you don't have to extend anything. Just implement the listener interface. The tutorial I linked to uses the built-in observer classes, that isn't really good, I'm sorry for that. Just search google for "observer pattern", you will find plenty of information but I'm surprised no good results come up for Java...